# How to play sound with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playback

I am struggling to make the play icon active and play a sound. Can anyone help me?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a id="play" href="#" class="btn">
        <audio id="myaudio">
            <source src="media/tasmanian-devil-daniel_simon.mp3" preload="auto"  > 
        </audio>
        <br>
        <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I need some javascript help. :)

Comment: its probably the URL for the audio is not right can you check the network tab in your dev tool?

Comment: I don't see any javascript you have used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add the `controls` attribute to your `<audio>` tag. That way you don't need the extra button(s).

It would look like this:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <audio id="myaudio" controls>
        <source src="media/tasmanian-devil-daniel_simon.mp3" preload="auto">
    </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, yes, but i just want to have a tine play icon - https://fontawesome.com/icons/play?style=solid

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 - with default control
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60185383/11719787) by Niels Bosman

Method 2 - with custom button

```
-- JS  
const myaudioInput = document.querySelector('#myaudio');

function playAudio() {
 myaudioInput.play();
}

-- HTML  
<i class="fa fa-play" onclick="playAudio()"></i>
```

to pause

```
myaudioInput.pause();
```

to restart

```
myaudioInput.pause();
myaudioInput.currentTime = 0;
myaudioInput.play();
```